# LINQ query to select all that don't match

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following LINQ query that selects all the pages that have a menu associated with them. I now want to pull out all the pages that don’t have a menu associated with them I.e.. all the pages in Pages that don’t exist in “**AssociatedPages**”.

```
var AssociatedPages = (from mm in db.MainMenus
                            join p in db.Pages on mm.MainMenuPageFK equals p.PageID
                        select p);

var unAssociatedPages = (from p in db.Pages
                            where ???
                            select p);
return View(unAssociatedPages);
```

I’ve done this before in SQL but I’m not sure on the LINQ syntax.

The setup is one MainMenu can have one too many Pages associated with it

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var unAssociatedPages =
    from p in db.Pages
    join mm in db.MainMenus on p.PageID equals mm.MainMenuPageFK into mms
    where !mms.Any()
    select p;
```

You may find that you need to pop in a couple of `.ToArray()` calls to improve performance.

Comment: Still a bit to learn about LINQ here! Any() was not in my vocabulary until just now. It works perfectly, thanks